# Inserting and updating data into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update

I have some problems with inserting and updating data into my database. Everything works fine expect one thing - the data is inserting and updating, but also inserting duplicated data into database (every time whet I run the script). My code looks like this:

```
mysql_query("
INSERT INTO database_name SET
ski_area_rid = '$SKI_RID',
ski_zone_id = '$ZONE_ID', 
ski_zone_zone_name = '$ZONE_NAME', 
ski_zone_zone_sort_order = '$ZONE_SORT_ORDER',
ski_zone_lift_id_lift = '$LIFT_ZONE_ID', 
ski_zone_lift_lift_name = '$LIFT_ZONE_LIFT_NAME', 
ski_zone_lift_lift_id_status = '$LIFT_ZONE_ID_STATUS', 
ski_zone_lift_opening_time = '$LIFT_ZONE_OPENING_TIME', 
ski_zone_lift_lift_update_date = '$LIFT_ZONE_UPDATE_DATE', 
ski_zone_lift_id_lift_type = '$LIFT_ZONE_ID_TYPE', 
ski_zone_lift_lift_type_name = '$LIFT_ZONE_TYPE_NAME'
") OR die(mysql_error());
echo 'DONE<br /><br />';

mysql_query("
UPDATE database_name SET 
ski_area_rid = '$SKI_RID',
ski_zone_id = '$ZONE_ID', 
ski_zone_zone_name = '$ZONE_NAME', 
ski_zone_zone_sort_order = '$ZONE_SORT_ORDER',
ski_zone_lift_id_lift = '$LIFT_ZONE_ID', 
ski_zone_lift_lift_name = '$LIFT_ZONE_LIFT_NAME', 
ski_zone_lift_lift_id_status = '$LIFT_ZONE_ID_STATUS', 
ski_zone_lift_opening_time = '$LIFT_ZONE_OPENING_TIME', 
ski_zone_lift_lift_update_date = '$LIFT_ZONE_UPDATE_DATE', 
ski_zone_lift_id_lift_type = '$LIFT_ZONE_ID_TYPE', 
ski_zone_lift_lift_type_name = '$LIFT_ZONE_TYPE_NAME'
WHERE ski_zone_lift_id_lift = '$LIFT_ZONE_ID' ") OR die(mysql_error());
echo 'UPDATED<br /><br />';
```

Comment: Can you please show it by using sqlfiddle.com?

Answer (score 1):

Because you always will insert. You have to check if the value exist if not than you will insert if it exists you will be updating it.

Take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html or

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

These two links will help you

Also please use PDO or Mysqli instead of mysql.